# iOS Coordinates for UITextField in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to scroll my table view so it display the cell which the user tapped (with UITextField) on top. But I can't get the coordinates of the UITextField in the UITableView. The code I have now is:

```
CGPoint point = [[self this].tableView convertPoint:self.activeField.frame.origin fromView:nil];
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [[self this].tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
NSLog(@"R:%i, S:%i", indexPath.row, indexPath.section); //always R:0, S:0

[[self this].tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

[self this] is a method which just returns the view casted to my custom object (maybe a bad name but this is beside the point). So my question is: "How do I get the correct coordinates of the tapped UITextField in a UITableView."

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `convertPoint toView` method

so instead of

```
CGPoint point = [[self this].tableView convertPoint:self.activeField.frame.origin fromView:nil];
```

use

```
CGPoint point = [self.tableView convertPoint:self.activeField.frame.origin toView:self.view];
```

Also instead of querying for fields origin and getting indexPath for that point.
You can subclass `UITextField` and add a custom `NSIndexPath` property.. which you can easily assign and later retrieve

Comment: The subclass is a great idea and probably the cleanest.

Comment: So easy now I did this and clean. Thank you and solved